# The "Shekhar Gurera"

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[How does it work?](http://www.shekhargurera.webs.com/mind_reader.htm)

**My attempt:**

Let $n$ be a natural number with two digits.

Let $S$ be the sum of the digits of the number $n$

divided $S$ and $n$ by $9:$

$$S=9\cdot q_1+r_1\\
n=9\cdot q_2+r_2\\
\Longrightarrow r_1=r_2$$

How can I explain why this is work, I have no idea how it reads my thoughts.

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $$\overline{ab}$$ is a two digit number, then

$$\overline{ab} = 10a + b$$

The sum of the digits is $a+b$. Therefore when you finish calculating what is asked, you get

$$10a + b - (a + b) = 9a$$

This is always a multiple of nine. Notice that in the table, all of the multiples of nine have the same symbol next to them.